# How to read parts of a command output (after a certain character) into a bash variable?

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a command that returns an output in the following form

```
># command
VAR1=ABC
VAR2=DEF
VAR3=123
```

And I want to read VAR1 and VAR3 from that command into a shell script. So logically, I run the following two commands

```
># command | grep VAR1
VAR1=ABC
># command | grep VAR3
VAR3=123
```

How do I capture only the part that comes after the first equal sign? (So that "${VAR1}" = "ABC" and "${VAR3}" = "123"). Also of note, there could be another equal sign in the vale of either variable, so I need to keep everything after the first equal sign, including subsequent ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
command | awk -F = '/VAR1|VAR3/{print substr($0, index($0, "=")+1)}'
ABC
123
```

**Breakup:**

```
/VAR1|VAR3/    # searches for VAR1 OR VAR3
index($0, "=") # search for = in the record
substr         # gets the substring after first =
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Now on to the part where I run it on a remote host :/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
># command | grep -oP '(?<=VAR1=).*'
ABC
># command | grep -oP '(?<=VAR3=).*'
123
```